# How to insert in loop again inside loop then Insert query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$product_id = $request->input("product_id");
$size_id = $request->input("size");
$price = $request->input("price");
$shade_id = $request->input("shade_id");
$arr = array();
if($shade_id){

    for($i=0; $i<count($shade_id); $i++){

        $shades_id = $shade_id[$i];
        if($size_id){
            for($j=0; $j<count($size_id); $j++){
                /*$insert = DB::table('tbl_product_shade_attributes')
                    ->insertGetId(['product_shade_id' => $shade_id[$i], 'product_id'=> $product_id,'size_id' => 1, 'price'=> 200]);*/

                $arr[$j] = [
                    'product_shade_id' => $shades_id,
                    'product_id'=> $product_id,
                    'size_id' => $size_id[$j], 
                    'price'=> $price[$j]
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not pretty sure why it doesn't insert properly data on the database.

1. My HTML Structure:
   [image: 1. My HTML Structure]
2. MY Database Structure
   [image: 2. MY Database Structure]
3. My output is displaying on the console log
   [image: 3. My output is displaying on the console log]

This is my FormData

[Please see my AJAX FormData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOxi2.png)

Comment: can you please update your request FormData in your question.

Comment: Please check to update my question  -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOxi2.png